React-Native Project: Navigation Issue
In my React-Native project, written in js, I'm having an issue with my routes. I'm using useNavigation and NavigationContainer from @react, initializing these routes using linking in the NavigationContainer.
Here's the issue: when I try manually entering a route (i.e. /artist/25), the page doesn't get taken there, but when I click a button that routes to that page, it works fine. I would be okay with that, but after manually entering the URL, I'm unable to mount the new page (i.e. the useEffect of the page that the button is pointed to isn't running anymore, meaning navigation.navigate isn't taking the user to the page.
Does anyone have an idea on what I should try? Let me know if you need more info at all, been stuck on this a while.

do you mind sharing some piece of your code?
